# Check if either column has value on inserting data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I have 3 columns in a table `C1, C2, C3` all `NVARCHAR` and `NULLABLE`.
I'm using SQL Server.

The catch is on inserting the data I need to check if at least 1 column has data in it.

For eg:
`Valid data` below:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | Hello | World |
| Hello | NULL | NULL |
| Hello | Dear | World |

`Invalid data` below:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Is it possible to add such a check on Insert operation?

Comment: Can you use a Procedure instead of a direct update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and even quite simple, but you should back that up with a check constraint, to also prevent updating the table to this invalid state.

Basically, something like this will do the trick:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table Name>  
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT 
<Constraint Name> CHECK  (([A] IS NOT NULL OR [B] IS NOT NULL OR [C] IS NOT NULL));
```

You can also use `COALESCE` for a shorter code:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table Name>  
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT 
<Constraint Name> CHECK (COALESCE([A],[B],[C]) IS NOT NULL);
```